# VBA COUNTIF for font color

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to create a COUNTIF which takes into account the text value and font color of a criteria string. This is what I've come up with so far. It's currently returning a #VALUE! error.

```
Function test(range As range, criteria As range) As Double

Dim cell As range
Dim criteriaLength As Integer
Dim counter As Integer

counter = 0

For Each cell In range
    If InStr(cell.value, criteria.value) > 0 And 
    cell.Characters(InStr(cell.value, criteria.value), 
    criteriaLength).Font.Color = criteria.Font.Color Then
         counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next cell
test = counter

End Function
```

The cells in the search range each contain characters of different font colors--that's why I'm using InStr and Characters. Any ideas what the issue might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never assign a value to `criteriaLength`

You need to add:

```
criteriaLength = Len(criteria)
```

before the loop.

And the If will try both sides of the And in the if and if the criteria is not in the string the second part will error.  You need to nest the if so the second only fires if the first returns True.

```
Function test(range As range, criteria As range) As Double

Dim cell As range
Dim criteriaLength As Integer
Dim counter As Integer

counter = 0
criteriaLength = Len(criteria)
For Each cell In range
    If InStr(cell.Value, criteria.Value) > 0 Then
        If cell.Characters(InStr(cell.Value, criteria.Value), criteriaLength).Font.color = criteria.Font.color Then
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    End If
Next cell
test = counter

End Function
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the help! I can't believe I forgot to define criteriaLength...

Comment: If it worked for you please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer